# TecTiles and applications

Tags: samsung, nfc, tectiles

Samsung promotes NFC via its [TecTiles](http://www.samsung.com/us/microsite/tectile/#multiple-uses), which is a very interesting concept but i cant find lots of information about it, especially the need for an app.

Do you know if a user that just want  to "read" the tag needs an app ([probably this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.tectiles2&feature=search_result#?t=W10)) on his side to be able to execute the action?

Does someone have experiences/feedback with this product?